# Using offsetTop or getBoundingClientRect().top returns the wrong value

Tags: javascript, css, web

I'm using `$0.getBoundingClientRect().top` or `$0.offsetTop` on an element in the inspector but it returns the wrong pixel value when compared to measuring the actual pixels using the screenshot tool, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> on a Mac.

I've been working the whole day with this, trying to use only inline styles, and copying and pasting the contents of the elements tab in the inspector into a new tab in `about:blank`. The funny thing is in the new tab it shows the correct value. Can JavaScript code tinker with this API? I'm using a virtual DOM library to generate the DOM nodes.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to reset the zoom? Actually when using pinch zoom the magnifying glass will not show up in the adress bar in Chrome... This is not good UX, but you need to press CMD + `+`, this will reveal the magnifying glass, then reset the zoom.

[image]